# C++ inline assembly trying to copy a char from a std::string into a register

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-c++, inline-assembly, stdstring

I have an assignment in C++ to read a file into a string variable which contains digits (no spaces), and using inline assembly, the program needs to sum up the digits of the string. For this I want to loop until end of string (NULL) and every iteration copy 1 char (which is 1 digit) into a register so I can use compare and subtract on it. The problem is that every time instead of copying the char to the register it copies some random value.

I'm using Visual Studio for debugging. Variable *Y* is the string and I'm trying to copy every iteration of the loop the current char into register AL.

```
    // read from txt file
string y;
cout << "\n" << "the text is \n";
ifstream infile;
infile.open("1.txt");
getline(infile, y);
cout << y;
infile.close();

    // inline assembly
_asm
{
    mov edx, 0          // counter
    mov ebx, 0
    mov eax, 0
loop1:  
    movzx AL, y[ebx]
    cmp AL, 0x00
    jz finished
    sub AL, 48          // convert ascii to number, assuming digit
    add edx, eax        // add digit to counter
    add ebx, 1          // move pointer to the next byte
    loop loop1
finished:
    mov i, edx
}
```

For example assuming *Y* is "123" and it's the first iteration of the loop, EBX is 0. I expect `y[ebx]` to point to value 49 ('1') and indeed in debug I see `y[ebx]`'s value is 49. I want to copy said value into a register, so when I use instruction:

> movzx AL, y[ebx]

I expect register AL to change to 49 ('1'), but the value changes to something random instead. For instance last debug session it changed to 192 ('À').

Comment: `std::string` is a non pod class type. It's significantly different from a `char*` (which you seem to assume in your assembly code).

Comment: I see, and I think I understand thank you. But the debugger does show y[ebx] value 49 type char, so I imagine there is probably some way you can access the individual chars of a string in assembly?

Comment: _"so I imagine there is probably some way you can access the individual chars of a string in assembly"_ Only by using function calls like `c_str()` or `operator[]`. I don't understand the purpose of using inline assembly in this case anyways though. It's rarely the case that you'll provide better optimizations that the compiler does.

Comment: Where the raw data in `std::string` is stored, is implementation defined. There might be allocated memory on heap. In certain cases it might be possible that packing bytes are used to store raw data inside (for very short raw data). However, `std::string::c_str()` provides a reliabe pointer to raw data (and `std::string::size()` the length of it). This is IMHO what you should use to access the data in ASM.

Comment: Please, remember that `49` can mean anything. It might be the representation of char `1` as well as just the least byte of `(int)49`. IMHO, finding the number `49` somewhere in memory doesn't mean anything without knowing what it is used for.

Comment: `movzx AL, y[ebx]` doesn't make sense.  move with zero-extension only makes sense with a wider destination, like `movzx eax, byte ptr y[ebx]`.  I'm surprised that assembles; there are no [forms of the `movzx` instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movzx) that have an 8-bit destination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`y` is the `std::string` object's control block.  You want to access its C string data.

MSVC inline asm syntax is pretty crap, so there's no way to just ask for a pointer to that in a register.  I think you have to create a new C++ variable like `char *ystr = y.c_str();`

That C variable is a *pointer* which you need to load into register with `mov ecx, [ystr]`.  Accessing the bytes of `ystr`'s object-representation directly would give you the bytes of the pointer.

Also, your current code is using the `loop` instruction, which is slow and equivalent to `dec ecx/jnz`.  But you didn't initialize ECX, and your loop termination condition is based on the zero terminator, not a counter that you know ahead of the first iteration.  (Unless you also ask the `std::string` for its length instead).

There is zero reason to use the `loop` instruction here.  Put a `test al,al / jnz loop1` at the bottom of your loop like a normal person.